# How do I insert new lines in a fixed length text file in NiFi using the ReplaceText processor with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, split, apache-nifi

I have a fixed-length text file that has only one line containing all of the 500-character records.  I want to insert new lines so that the file contains only one 500-character record per line, with the number of lines being the number of records.  Using the Regex, I put

> (.{1000})*

in the **Search Value** field, and

> ((.{500})**<shift+enter>**(.{500}))*

in the **Replacement Value** field.  The resulting file contains just the literal replacement.

> ((.{500})
> (.{500})*(.{500})
> (.{500}))*

What am I missing in the configuration?  Is there something wrong in my regular expressions?

Comment: Right, you need backreferences, `$1` to Group 1, `$2` to Group 2 values, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I apply those to the regex?

Comment: Since I cannot test, you may try `.{500}` and replace it with `$0\n` (I used `\n` to denote line break).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody, for your help.  Here is what I did to get it to work.

Search Value:

> **(.{500})(.{500})**

Replacement Value:

> **$1**<shift+enter>**$2**<shift+enter>

The **$1** backreferences the first **(.{500})** group, and the **$2** backreferences the second **(.{500})** group.  The **<shift+enter>** introduces the newlines.